# Get a list of dead keys in X11

Tags: c, keyboard, x11

Is there a way to check for dead keys in the current layout? I am currently capturing the users input for a project I am doing. I created a map of all keys on the keyboard, but there seems to be no flag or whatsoever defining a key as dead or not. I use `libxkb` in my current code.

The layout is retrieved using

```
KeySym * keysyms = XGetKeyboardMapping(display_, keycode_low, keycode_high - keycode_low + 1, &num_keysym);
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand you need to know which key will not directly produce a character, maybe because you are writing a game and do not want to have it use keys as input that would require another key to be pressed to produce some output (if so, please mention in the question)

Not through standard Xlib calls, to my knowledge, and definitely not without actually *pressing* the respective key. Composing is entirely done within Xlib, and transparent to the front end. (For its original purpose, it should be as transparent as possible to work properly, after all)

You could, however, do the same thing that Xlib does and parse through the various *Compose* configuration files starting with $HOME/.Xcompose. But that could be a tedious process.

On second thought, I am **definitely not proposing the following:**

You could, for each key you are looking for information, create a synthetic keypress event and feed it into *XLookupString*. Hand in an emptied XComposeStatus structure as well. If the structure returns modified, this could be a strong hint you have found a compose key. But it could also mean the server modifies it without any need..... If I were very desparate, I'd probably try.

Comment: Currently I relay on the xkbcommond-keysym table. There is a list of all dead keys in there. But this may change someday...